# Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type 'MiddlewareFunc'. app.use(oakCors());

Tags: deno

I am getting this error when I am trying to add cors in deno.

Argument of type '(context: { request: any; response: any; }, next: (...args: any) => any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MiddlewareFunc'.
app.use(oakCors());

```js
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/abc@v1.0.0-rc8/mod.ts";
import { getAllBlogs, getBlogById, addNewBlog } from './controllers/index.ts';
import { oakCors } from "https://deno.land/x/cors/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();

app
.use(oakCors())
.get('/blogs', getAllBlogs)
.get('/blog/:id', getBlogById)
.post('/add-blog', addNewBlog)
.start({ port: 8000 })
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttMG8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cors` exports middlewares for different frameworks, you should use `abcCors` for `abc` and not `oakCors` which is for `Oak`.

```
import { abcCors } from "https://deno.land/x/cors/mod.ts";
```